# What is the directions_extension in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

At the moment I am building a Rails 3.1 application and have it running perfectly. However, I noticed that my markup currently contains this element on all pages:

```
<div id="directions_extension" style="position: absolute !important; background-image: initial !important; background-attachment: initial !important; background-origin: initial !important; background-clip: initial !important; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 255) !important; border-top-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 1px !important; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-left-width: 1px !important; border-top-style: solid !important; border-right-style: solid !important; border-bottom-style: solid !important; border-left-style: solid !important; border-top-color: rgb(170, 170, 255) !important; border-right-color: rgb(170, 170, 255) !important; border-bottom-color: rgb(170, 170, 255) !important; border-left-color: rgb(170, 170, 255) !important; padding-top: 3px !important; padding-right: 3px !important; padding-bottom: 3px !important; padding-left: 3px !important; display: none; border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px !important; border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px !important; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px !important; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px !important; background-position: initial initial !important; background-repeat: initial initial !important; "></div>
```

Im not sure where this element is coming from. I've checked my layout and made sure everything is closed properly, but still no catch of where it might be coming from. My template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="biotech tools for the future">
    <meta name="keywords" content="biotech, biotechnology, tools, dna, analysis">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <title>bioDome :: reliable and stable bio tools</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "libs/modernizr.min" %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>bioDome</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><%= link_to 'home', root_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'contact', contact_path  %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'users', users_path %></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header><!-- header -->
        <div id="main" role="main">
            <section id="<%= params[:controller] %>" class="<%= "#{params[:controller]}-#{params[:action]}" %>">
                <%= yield %>
            </section>
        </div><!-- #main -->
        <footer>

        </footer> <!-- footer -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea where this directions_extension might be coming from, and if so, how to remove it?

Comment: Did you search your code base? Did you search inside the code of the gems that you use? Use `grep` or do a project-wide search in your editor.

Comment: Yes I did. Nothing came up with a grep search. It has to be part of the Rails 3.1 framework because I created a new rails app on another mac and the same thing was in the generated html.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check your browser extensions. I was trying to figure out the same thing, then realized it was coming from the Chrome extension "Select to get maps." I disabled it and it went away. Looks like that extension writes the div to most every page.